# How to add same recipient in docusign API with different routing order?

Tags: docusignapi

I have a use case where the recipient has to just click "approve" button on receiving the envelope first time, then the same recipient has to sign when receiving envelope for the second time in routing order.

I am getting the below error message when adding the recipient twice with different routing order in API.

```
{
    "errorCode": "ENVELOPE_HAS_DUPLICATE_RECIPIENTS",
    "message": "The specified envelope has duplicate recipients."
}
```

How can the same recipient be added twice in the API with different routing order and different tabs in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a person to appear twice in the recipient routing if you include `allowRecipientRecursion: true` in your envelope request definition.

The `allowRecipientRecursion` element is part of the top-level envelope definition object.

Comment: I'm set the allowRecipientRecursion : true but I still get the same error. Any idea?

Comment: @FredericoAlmeida -- Sorry you're having trouble. Please edit your question to include the DocuSign trace showing the failed request. Omit any private info (email addresses, etc). See [how to trace](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-api-request-logging)

Comment: I actually found the solution to the problem. allowRecipientRecursion : true is not enough. We have to make sure that the repeated recipients are in different Signing Order.